# Regex HTTP header parsing

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use Regex to get a bit if HTTP header parsing done. I'd like to use groups to organize some of the information:

Let's say I have this:

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="item1"`

I'd like the result of my regex to create two groups:

```
contentdisposition : form-data
name : item1
```

I've tried several methods, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. If name= doesn't exist then only one group should be created, but the regex should not error out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Simple parsing could be more suited for the given situation, headers are usually pretty predictable. If you want to go the regex route, please add a tag of the language you're using, you'll get a lot more answers that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/Content-Disposition: (.*?);(?: name="(.*?)")?/` might be what you're looking for.  It uses an optional greedy quantifier to get the name unless that would cause the match to fail.